# Filter rows of one column on the condition that rows in all other columns are NA, and repeat for n columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, na

Apologies if this has been asked before; I wasn't quite sure how to phrase the question, which might have prevented other questions from showing up in my search.

My situation is that I have a data set like this:

```
toy <- 
  data.frame(
    Serves_1 = c("yes", NA, "yes", "no", "yes", "no"),
    Serves_2 = c(NA, NA, "no", "no", "no", "yes"),
    Serves_3 = c(NA, "no", "yes", "no", NA, "no"),
    Serves_4 = c(NA, "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")
  )
toy
```

I'm trying to determine how many rows have a non-NA for one column and NAs for all other columns. So take for example, column Serves_1:

```
toy %>%
  filter(
    !is.na(Serves_1) &
      is.na(Serves_2) &
      is.na(Serves_3) &
      is.na(Serves_4)
  ) %>%
  nrow
```

There is one row where Serves_1 has a non-NA value and, simultaneously, all other columns have NA for that row.

This code works fine, but I need to repeat this procedure for each column. I could just move the exclamation mark down the line for each column. But in my real dataset, I have to do this for over 20 columns.

Is there a more efficient way to do this (preferably using dplyr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowSums`:

```
library(dplyr)
toy <- 
  data.frame(
    Serves_1 = c("yes", NA, "yes", "no", "yes", "no"),
    Serves_2 = c(NA, NA, "no", "no", "no", "yes"),
    Serves_3 = c(NA, "no", "yes", "no", NA, "no"),
    Serves_4 = c(NA, "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(na_sum = rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

This gives you:

```
  Serves_1 Serves_2 Serves_3 Serves_4 na_sum
1      yes     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>      3
2     <NA>     <NA>       no      yes      2
3      yes       no      yes      yes      0
4       no       no       no       no      0
5      yes       no     <NA>      yes      1
6       no      yes       no       no      0
```

You can then filter rows where `na_sum` == 3 to get all rows where one value is not NA and the rest are:

```
toy %>% 
  filter(na_sum ==3)
```

Which gives us:

```
  Serves_1 Serves_2 Serves_3 Serves_4 na_sum
1      yes     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>      3
```

Comment: This is a really clever workaround Matt, thank you for this!

Comment: No problem! Please consider marking the answer as complete by clicking the green check mark if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

additional option

```
sum(apply(toy, 1, function(x) (length(x) - 1 == sum(is.na(x)))))
```